# .net functions of an exe used in excel. how to use some of the variables of the exe which may change in other functions or on load?

Tags: c#

I am using some of the functions of .net application in excel through COM. But whenever i call some function of the .net, i need to open exe and send some values to the form of the exe and use some of the values from the running exe. How do i do this? please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WCF as intermediatary between excel and .net , it works like charm..